# How do I get PDF-Shuffler onto the Open With menu?

Tags: pdf

I've right-clicked on pdf icons, chosen open with/other application/show other applications, but PDF-Shuffler does not appear on any list.  It is installed.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, the `Exec` parameter in the desktop file has not the right value for that. You need

```
Exec=pdfshuffler %f
```

`%f` means a single file as parameter

or

```
Exec=pdfshuffler %F
```

`%F` means all selected files as parameter

instead of

```
Exec=pdfshuffler
```

---

*Therefore*

1. Copy the desktop file in you home folder

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/pdfshuffler.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
2. Correct the ownership

   ```
   sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.local/share/applications/pdfshuffler.desktop
   ```
3. Open the file in an editor

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/pdfshuffler.desktop
   ```
4. Correct the `Exec` parameter

   ```
   Exec=pdfshuffler %f
   ```
5. Close all nautilus processes

   ```
   nautilus -q
   ```
6. Open the context menu of the pdf document and select <kbd>Open With Other Application</kbd>
7. Select <kbd>View All Applications</kbd>
8. Search and select <kbd>PDF-Shuffler</kbd>

   [image]